# Can moonshine be explained by the $q$-expansion map $\mathrm{tmf} \to KU[[q]]$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, brauer-groups

If we form an equivariant version of both sides of the $q$-expansion map $\mathrm{tmf} \to KU[[q]]$ (with everything being $p$-completed), should the equivariant $q$-expansion map should have something to do with moonshine?

The Brauer lift gives a map $\operatorname{Rep}_{F_q}(G) \to \operatorname{Rep}_{C}(G)$. Is the moonshine module in the image of this map?

Is there any reference to literature regarding this, because I am almost certain that this idea is not original?

Comment: Key phrases to look for are divided congruences (in the sense of Katz) and $K(1)$-local topological modular forms.